# IE Select text align center

Tags: css, internet-explorer, select, center, text-align

I'm trying to put a item at select in center at Ie. But it doesn't  works. How can I do it?

```
<style type="text/css">
    select
    {
        width: 400px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<asp:ListBox ID="lsb" runat="server" Width="250px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="text" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="text" />
</asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but did you try:
    select { width: 400px; margin:0 auto; }

Comment: I don't think you got it. The problem is, at Chrome the items are at the center, but at IE it doesn't works, the item text still align to left.

Comment: try select > option {text-align: center}

Comment: select > option {text-align: center} works at chrome
But it doesn't works at IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to apply style in item as a select on Internet Explorer. 
Sad, but is true.